# magento all new newsletter subscriptions becomes Unsubscribed after adding mailchimp for magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

after adding module mailchimp for magento installed all new newsletter subscriptions becomes Unsubscribed. not confirmation email sending.

https://github.com/mailchimp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

comment out this part in the observer will fix the issue

```
public function handleSubscriber(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)

    if (true === $subscriber->getIsStatusChanged()) {
    Mage::getModel('mailchimp/api_subscribers')->updateSubscriber($subscriber, true);
    } else {
    $origData = $subscriber->getOrigData();

    if (is_array($origData) && isset($origData['subscriber_status'])
    && $origData['subscriber_status'] != $subscriber->getSubscriberStatus()
    ) {
    Mage::getModel('mailchimp/api_subscribers')->updateSubscriber($subscriber, true);
    }
}
```